# Extract the last forecast

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have the following data.frame:

```
forecast_date      applicable_at        forecasted_value
 2008-01-01         2008-01-10            155
 2008-01-04         2008-01-10            152
 2008-01-06         2008-01-10            144
 2008-01-02         2008-01-10            145
 2008-01-03         2008-01-10            148
 2008-01-05         2008-01-10            151
```

.............................................

The data.frame goes until 2015-12-20

I want to extract from this data.frame only the last forecast which would be:

```
forecast_date      applicable_at        forecasted_value
 2008-01-06         2008-01-10            144
```

I tried using `data.table package` and `setDT` function but I was not able to extract it correctly. Could you please help me with this? Also, I was not able to solve this with the subset function either.

[image]

I have tried:

```
newDF <- setDT(df)[, list(LastDate = max(forecast_date)), by = list(applicable_at)]
```

and

```
newDF <- subset(df, df$applicable_at == df$applicable_at & max(df$forecast_date))
```

Comment: please include a reproducible example. What did you try?

Comment: @MLavoie  I've tried this:                                                                    newDF <- setDT(df)[, list(LastDate = max(forecast_date)), by = list(applicable_at)]   and                                                                     newDF <- subset(df, df$applicable_at == df$applicable_at & max(df$forecast_date))

Comment: If you are looking for the most recent forecast and they aren't always in the last position this should work: `information.dat[ which( as.Date( information.dat$forecast_date ) - Sys.Date() == min( as.Date( information.dat$forecast_date ) - Sys.Date() ) ) , ]`

Comment: @joran, thank you for the edit

Comment: @Badger thank you for the edit

Comment: @Badger, I used Ven Yao's answer and it did work for me. Thanks for your help and time, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text1="forecast_date      applicable_at        forecasted_value
2008-01-01         2008-01-10            155
2008-01-04         2008-01-10            152
2008-01-06         2008-01-10            144
2008-01-02         2008-01-10            145
2008-01-03         2008-01-15            148
2008-01-05         2008-01-15            151"

dat <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T)
```

using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(applicable_at) %>% filter(forecast_date==max(forecast_date))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: applicable_at

#   forecast_date applicable_at forecasted_value
# 1    2008-01-06    2008-01-10              144
# 2    2008-01-05    2008-01-15              151
```

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dat)
setkey(dt, applicable_at)

dt[, V1:=max(forecast_date), by=applicable_at][forecast_date == V1]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
setDT(dat)[, V1:=max(forecast_date), by=applicable_at][forecast_date == V1]
```

Comment: thanks, Ven Yao. The first code (using dplyr) worked for me. I didn't try the second option (data.table) just because I was able to write only one line for dplyr.  Thanks again, NIck

Comment: Thanks. Got it. @Arun